# Implementing pass-by-reference argument semantics in an interpreter

Tags: programming-languages, parameter-passing, interpreter, pass-by-reference

Pass-by-value semantics are easy to implement in an interpreter (for, say, your run-of-the-mill imperative language). For each scope, we maintain an environment that maps identifiers to their values. Processing a function call involves creating a new environment and populating it with copies of the arguments.

This won't work if we allow arguments that are passed by reference. How is this case typically handled?

Comment: Populate the function call's new environment with a copy of the references. How else would you do it?

Comment: If I pass an "int" (say, in C++) by reference, I don't have a reference that I can copy, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your interpreter must check that the argument is something that can be passed by reference – that the argument is something that is legal in the left-hand side of an assignment statement.  For example, if `f` has a single pass-by-reference parameter, `f(x)` is  okay (since `x := y` makes sense) but `f(1+1)` is not (`1+1 := y` makes no sense).  Typical qualifying arguments are variables and variable-like constructs like array indexing (if `a` is an array for which `5` is a legal index, `f(a[5])` is okay, since `a[5] = y` makes sense).

If the argument passes that check, it will be possible for your interpreter to determine while processing the function call which precise memory location it refers to.  When you construct the new environment, you put a reference to that memory location as the value of the pass-by-reference parameter.  What that reference concretely looks like depends on the design of your interpreter, particularly on how you represent variables: you could simply use a pointer if your implementation language supports it, but it can be more complex if your design calls for it (the important thing is that the reference must make it possible for you to retrieve and modify the value contained in the memory location being referred to).

while your interpreter is interpreting the body of a function, it may have to treat pass-by-referece parameters specially, since the enviroment does not contain a proper value for it, just a reference.  Your interpreter must recognize this and go look what the reference points to.  For example, if `x` is a local variable and `y` is a pass-by-reference parameter, computing `x+1` and `y+1` may (depending on the details of your interpreter) work differently: in the former, you just look up the value of `x`, and then add one to it; in the latter, you must look up the reference that `y` happens to be bound to in the environment and go look what value is stored in the variable on the far side of the reference, and then you add one to it.  Similarly, `x = 1` and `y = 1` are likely to work differently: the former just goes to modify the value of `x`, while the latter must first see where the reference points to and modify whatever variable or variable-like thing (such as an array element) it finds there.

You could simplify this by having all variables in the environment be bound to references instead of values; then looking up the value of a variable is the same process as looking up the value of a pass-by-reference parameter.  However, this creates other issues, and it depends on your interpreter design and on the details of the language whether that's worth the hassle.